# Гибкая функция для изменения атрибута VALUE нескольких кнопок submit на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице несколько одинаковых форм с одинаковым функционалом.  Проблема заключается в переменной `total` . Если будет две формы, то при выборе какого-нибудь чекбокса в одной форме - `total` меняется и для другой, что приводит к неправильным подсчетам.

Как можно сделать свою переменную `total` для каждой формы?

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var total = 10;

          $(".onemore").click(function() {

            if ($('input', this).is(":checked")) {
              total = total - 5;
              $(this).closest(".form").find(".ppbutton").attr("value", "ORDER NOW (" + total + "$)");
              $('input', this).prop("checked", false);
              $('a', this).css("color", "black");

            } else

            {
              total = total + 5;
              $(this).closest(".form").find(".ppbutton").attr("value", "ORDER NOW (" + total + "$)");
              $('input', this).prop("checked", true);
              $('a', this).css("color", "#00beff");

            }
          });
          $(".extrafast").click(function() {

            if ($('input', this).is(":checked")) {
              total = total - 10;
              $(this).closest(".form").find(".ppbutton").attr("value", "ORDER NOW (" + total + "$)");
              $('input', this).prop("checked", false);
              $('a', this).css("color", "black");

            } else

            {
              total = total + 10;
              $(this).closest(".form").find(".ppbutton").attr("value", "ORDER NOW (" + total + "$)");
              $('input', this).prop("checked", true);
              $('a', this).css("color", "#00beff");

            }
          });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="paypal">
      <form class="form"><table class="checkboxes">
        <tr class="head" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">
          <td class="firstone">
            <input type="hidden" name="item1" value="Item 1" checked>
          </td>
          <td class="secondone">Basic Gig</td>
          <td class="thirdone">$10.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="onemore">
          <td class="firstone">&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input class="onemore_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="item2" value="Item2">
          </td>
          <td class="secondone middle onemoretext" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">
            <label class="onemore_checkbox"><a>One more variant of interior</a>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td class="thirdone middle onemoretext" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">
            <label class="onemore_checkbox"><a>$5.00</a>
            </label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="extrafast">
          <td class="firstone">&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input class="extrafast_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="item3" value="Item3">
          </td>
          <td class="secondone extrafasttext">
            <label class="extrafast_checkbox"><a>Extra fast 1day delivery</a>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td class="thirdone extrafasttext">
            <label class="extrafast_checkbox"><a>$10.00</a>
            </label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="item4" value="Item4" checked>
        </table>

        <table class="pp">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input class="ppbutton" type="submit" border="0" name="payment" value="ORDER NOW (10$)" />
            </td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: поработайте с массивами total[i] к примеру относится к form[i]. У вас там каша с table.

Comment: А можно поподробнее, как вы предлагаете это сделать? Я бы хотел избежать дублирования скрипта.